# Android Studio WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a WebView and I need to open a few Websites which are saved in a Array one after the other. This should been repeated infinity times and each Website should be stayed open for **x** seconds.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String[] links = {"https://www.google.at/?gws_rd=ssl", "http://stackoverflow.com/"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    while(true) {
        myWebView.loadUrl(links[0]);
        myWebView.loadUrl(links[1]);
    }
}
```

If I try to open just one link without a loop it is working. But if I try it with the loop it Shows me a blackscreen.

Comment: Use thread   Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                  //URL HERE
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        th.start();

Comment: @RakshitNawani It don't work how expected

Comment: You can use "onPageFinished" when ever a page is finished loading, the controller goes here and you can load the new page here

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try this

```
int position=0;
textview.setText("page started");
browser.loadUrl("your first url");
browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
{
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
   {
      if(progress == 100)
      {
         textview.setText("page finished");
         if(position==0)
         {
           browser.loadUrl("your second url");
           position=1;
           textview.setText("page started");
         } 
         if(position==1)
         {
           browser.loadUrl("your third url");
           position=2;
           textview.setText("page started");
         } 
      }
   }
```

});

for more details refer this link [How to load URL consecutively one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297535/how-to-load-url-consecutively-one-by-one)